# python derived class constructor

Tags: python-3.x

a very dumb question, if we write `__init__(self, ..)` in our derived class then the derived class will no longer inherit the parent class's constructor because we overwrite it, if we want to keep using the constructor from the parent class we need to write `parentClass.__init__(self, ..)`. However I noticed it is not true

```
class Item:
    def __init__(self,name= '',quantity = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.quantity = quantity

    def set_name(self, nm):
        self.name = nm

    def set_quantity(self, qnty):
        self.quantity = qnty

    def display(self):
        print(self.name, self.quantity)


class Produce(Item):  # Derived from Item
    def __init__(self,expiration = ''):
        self.expiration = expiration

    def set_expiration(self, expir):
        self.expiration = expir

    def get_expiration(self):
        return self.expiration

item2 = Produce()
item2.set_name('Apples')
item2.set_quantity(40)
item2.set_expiration('May 5, 2012')

print(item2.name,item2.quantity)
```

I can still access the parent class' attribute `name` and `quantity` without using `Item.__init__(self)`
Could someone give me some hints why it works? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `name` and `quantity` are created in your `set_...()` methods.

In python, any method can create attributes on a class; it's usually considered bad style to do so, but there's no problem doing it - the only concern is that it can be confusing.

BTW, speaking of style - in python it's usually better style to omit setters and use `item2.name = 'Apples'` rather than  `item2.set_name('Apples')`. If a setter is needed later, `name` can be turned into a property, overriding what happens on `item2.name = 'Apples'`